# Yii2 set varaible in controller class

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

i am using yii2 advanced app, I want to set a variable in a controller class which will be used in all the actions of that controller. How can i do this, Can anyone help?

Comment: you can set it in model. for what purpose you want to use that variable

Comment: ignore list for reporting purpose

Comment: please post your controller code

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by making **protected function** in u'r controller and return u'r variable

UserController.php

```
public function actionView() {
            $currentDate =  $this->getDate();  
}
public function actionList() { 
           $currentDate =  $this->getDate();  
}


protected function getDate($id) { 
           return $currentDate =  date('d-m-Y');  
}
```

Hope this will work for you